# Calculating charge entered into a circuit element for a given time

Tags: current, charge

Looking at p 1.2-4 in [Introduction to Electric Circuits by Dorf](https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/1689468335583987/Introduction%20to%20Electric%20Circuits,%209th%20Edition%20-%20Richard%20C.%20Dorf,%20James%20A.%20Svoboda.pdf) (See top of p16)

> [image]

I don't understand why the charge for 4 < t < 8 is 8- t.

The current for that time is given as -1. So getting charge by integrating that gives -t, over the period 8 to 4.

At the lower bound, it will be -4, so I thought the answer should be:

integral upperbound - integral lowerbound

and if upperbound is taken as an aribtrary point t, within the range, 4

it would be = -t - (-4) = 4 -t.

So why does it become 8-t?

Comment: page #?   ..................

Comment: Please post the diagram into your question so we don't all have to follow a link.

Comment: top of page 16. I think I may have figured it out though... the question is asking for total current, so the extra 4 is accounted for the charge entered into the circuit up to that point not just from the lower bound (ie t =4 ), but from - infinity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 2 to 4s, the 2A current increases the charge from 0 to 4C (coulombs) in 2 seconds.  From 4 to 8, the -1A current decreases the charge from 4 to 0C in 4 seconds.  That means it's 4 at T=4, and 0 at T=8.  That's a segment of the line 8-T, as is easily verified by extending it to the Y axis.

It may be more clear if you draw the charge over time.

Answer (score 0):

Within the range for t= 4 to 8 the time integral starts at 4 with an interval of 4 and ends at 8 with a difference = 0

thus "8-t"
for t=4 to 8 ... "8-4"= 4 sec duration * I(t=4~8) = amp-seconds  added to total

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand, I think im misunderstanding something at a more fundamental level. what do you mean by difference = 0? as in difference between what and what?